# Coffeescript with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have just started learning Rails, is it required for me to learn CoffeeScript as well? Where it becomes useful?

Comment: Very open question, not sure if that conforms to the normal format here. Short answer is: No, you have not.

Comment: coffeescript is not required to learn for Rails but good if you do. if you check their website (coffeescript.org) you will see their examples and can learn how it will be useful for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to know coffeescript to learn rails. While Coffeescript is the default as of rails 3.1 you can change it to use pure javascript instead. To do so:

1. Comment out gem "coffee-script" in your Gemfile
2. Use .js instead of .js.coffee for your javascript files